# ¿Por qué me sale el error: Errno 2?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando en python y tengo un archivo .txt, sin embrago al realizar el llamado me aparece el error "errno 2" y no se el por que  no me deja visualizar el contenido
¿Cómo hago para que me deje leerlo?

```
a = open('Ejercicio_1.txt', 'r')
c = a.read()
print(c)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: hola, ¿verificaste si el archivo `Ejercicio_1.txt` se encuentra en la misma ruta del programa? igualmente podrías copiar la dirección completa del archivo `Ejercicio_1.txt` ejemplo `C://../.../Ejercicio_1.txt`  y recuerda  siempre cerrar los archivos  `a.close()`

Comment: Yo no me sé los errores de memoria, agrega el error completo por favor

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.